# React Native - Type Script - Object should be changeble to a number when user clicks add

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-native, object

My question is, what should I modify on the interface so the number before the object (0, 1, ...) is generated automatically when the user click Add?

```
   export interface IRoute {
          amount?: string;
          id?: number;
          location?: string
        }

export const initialRoute: IRoute = {
  amount: '',
  id: 0,
  location: ''
}

 const [route, setRoute] = useState<IRoute[]>([initialRoute]);
 const nextId = route[route.length - 1].id + 1;
 const onAdd = () =>{[...prevState, {amount: '54', id: nextId, 'text'}]}
```

When the user clicks onAdd the response should look like this:

expected Behaviour:

```
route: [
       {0:{amount: '45', id: nextId , location: 'Test'}}, 
       {1:{amount: '35', id: nextId , location: 'Test'}}
      ]
```

actual Behaviour

```
route: [
       {amount: '45', id: nextId , location: 'Test'}, 
       {amount: '35', id: nextId , location: 'Test'}
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here.

1. The code for `onAdd` doesn't do anything, and shouldn't compile because `prevState` is undefined.  The function states, but does'nt do anything with, the new array.  I would expect it to be something like `const onAdd = () => setRoute([...route, <newObj>]);` or `const onAdd = () => setRoute((prevState) => [...prevState, <newObj>]);`
2. You're not telling it to create the object the way you want it set.  You would need something like `setRoute([...prevState, { [nextId]: <newObj> })`.
3. If you want `0` and `1` to be the indexes of the array, you don't need to make them object keys, you can access them by index in the array you have by doing `route[index]`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I applied your changes but I have another question. How do I access the parameters of the object that is like this                             setRoute([...prevState, { [nextId]: <newObj> }) . I can't seem to access anything inside the <newObj> becuase of the [nextId]

Comment: Like for example I want to increase the index and also the ID parameter. I can't seem to be able to access the ID parameter.

Comment: How familiar are you with object and array structures? If you're not feeling confident yet, I can send some resources. Objects can be accessed with dot notation `obj.key` or array notation `obj['key']`. Arrays are objects, but it's easier to think of them as sequential collections. You can only access them with array notation `obj[0]` and the keys can only be ints.

Comment: So if you want to create a collection of these objects, it could just be `const list = [<obj1, obj2, obj3>]`. You could get the first one by writing `list[0]`. If you want to use the list id in your object name, `const onAdd = () => setRoute([ ...route, { id: route.length, ... } ])` would work.

Comment: I managed to solve it based on your explenation. Thank you for your help